# Developing and debugging AWS Lambda Function: conda -> docker image using Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a project that involves developing an AWS Lambda function in Python. At the end I want to use a Docker image containing my custom code. I want to use the following steps:

1. Develop and debug the code locally using a conda virtual environment - No problem
2. Debug the code within the Docker image. - No problem
3. Push the Docker image to AWS ECR and deploy it as an AWS Lambda
   function.- No problem

My question what I need to to between step 1 and step 2, to switch from a conda environment to docker and be able to start the code. I also want to be able to switch back (my assumption is to use the command "Python: select interpreter"). What do I need to do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. If anyone else needs to know. My starting point was the setup I used for debugging using docker. I did this:

1. Run command "Python: select interpreter" and selected my conda environment.
2. In launch.json I added the following configuration: Add Configuration - Python
3. When I want to run docker I use "Invoke Lambda" and if I want to use conda "Python"

Simple when you have figured it out but easy to spend a lot of time on.